# How to refresh bootstrap data api if I dynamically create a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I am using http://rmariuzzo.github.io/checkboxes.js/ this plugin to limit my checkbox max choices.

However, if I add following code statically, it works great. If I add following section by dynamically creating via javascript, it does not work properly. **I guess because I add it dynamically so that data attribute does not get rendered. How can I solve it?**

PS: I search through Google and did not find any thing in bootstrap like 'trigger' or 'refresh' which are available in Jquery Mobile

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" data-toggle="checkboxes" data-max="1" name="selection1">
        <p>主食(选择一项)<br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="dishId"> T骨牛扒<span class="related-spec"></span><span class="related-num"></span></label>
            <label><input type="checkbox"> 台式大鸡排adsfasdf</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox"> 葱香猪扒asdfasdf</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox"> 安格斯牛排asd</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox"> 菲力牛排as</label>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, if you use the `$(mainSelector).on(event, childSelector, handler)` method of event binding, the `mainSelector` will listen for the `event`, which will then bind the `handler` function to the elements matching `childSelector` that are children of `mainSelector` *when the event is fired* rather than on page load. This allows it to be bound to dynamic elements. It may sound pretty complicated, but it's simple in application.

```
// this event will trigger any time something within the body
// of the page is loaded because of how events "bubble up"
// this binds the event on the selectors *when* the event triggers, 
// rather than once on page load only on the static elements.

$('body').on('load', 'div[data-toggle=checkboxes]', function(){
    $(this).checkboxes(); // checkboxes on matched element
});
```